# Getting similar colors using alpha channel

Tags: css, colors

There is something I could not figure out can anybody help me?
How can two colors be so similar with so differenet RGB values?
Like

#p1 {background-color:rgba(174,255,174,0.6);}

#p2 {background-color:rgba(0,255,0,0.2);}

and

#p4 {background-color:rgba(10,10,10,0.1);}

#p5 {background-color:rgba(210,210,210,0.5);}

The first one is a kind of green and the second one is kind of gray.
RGB should determine the color but what difference does those two color schemas have if they look the same?
Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean by two colors being the **same**? The color `#p1` and `#p2` looks similar but not exactly the same.

Comment: Note: many screens cannot display good colours, and many panel's screen display just 6-bit (per channel) colours.

Comment: I feel I need to clarify the question more. Here is the thing
while RGB (174,255,174) is very differnt from rgb(0,255,0) How does alpha chanel makes them seem so similar? Where is the trick?
Lİke wise while rbg (10,10,10) is very different than rgb (210,210,210) How does alpha chanel makes them seem so similar? Where is the trick?
what I belive ise I can make RGB (1,1,1) look like rgb (254,254,254) with the right alpha channel adjustment. How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Color rendering and color perception are complicated subjects. Different devices may make colors look slightly different and even more complex is human color perception.

To me on my laptop screen the two greens look almost identical, but the grays look different and I perceive a noticeable line between the two.

You can notice a definite difference between the rendering of the transparency when you put  a black background behind, as in the bottom half of this snippet.

So, the colors may appear the same to some people/on some devices but they are definitely not the same either in basic amount of r, g, b or in transparency.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  }
#bg {
  width: 80vw;
  height: 50vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50vh;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: -1;
} 
#p1, #p2, #p4, #p5 {
 width: 20vw;
 height: 100vh;
 float:left;
}
#p1 {background-color:rgba(174,255,174,0.6);}

#p2 {background-color:rgba(0,255,0,0.2);}

#p4 {background-color:rgba(10,10,10,0.1);}

#p5 {background-color:rgba(210,210,210,0.5);}
```

```html
<div id="bg"></div>
<div id="p1"></div>
<div id="p2"></div>
<div id="p4"></div>
<div id="p5"></div>
```